# Сравнение чисел без if, С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Помогите пожалуйста с задачей на C++.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Нельзя:** встроенный abs, ператоры сравнения, if.
**Можно:** арифметические операции, div, mod, функции из cmath (кроме abs), квадратный корень, возведение в степень. Также можно приводить к любому типу данных и взаимодействовать с ним.

Если нужно, можете ипользовать вместо модуля данное выражение

```
sqrt(a * a)
```

Наверняка есть какая-то математическая формула, просто нужно её придумать. Также по возможности не используйте логические опреаторы.

**UPD:** написал решение, но выдаёт ошибку в процессе выполнения, помогите исправить.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << (long long)((a + b + sqrt((a - b) * (a - b))) / 2) / a;
}
```

Comment: Когда задаете такие вопросы, давайте, пожалуйста, URL

Comment: На что URL? Тестирующей системы нет в открытом доступе.

Comment: Тогда это будет испорченный телефон - написал-отправил-вы проверили-ответили-и все заново...

Comment: @Harry пожалуйста не сбивайте людей с толку. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным, без всяких URL.

Comment: @Kromster Не сбивайте людей с толку. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным - не означает, что в вопросе не может быть URL. Есть одно ограничение - если URL не работает - вопрос (и ответ) должны оставаться достаточными для понимания, содержать в себе всю основную информацию. При этом может иметься дополнительная, облегчающая ответ и понимание информация - в том числе ссылки. Если вам просто очень хочется прицепиться - то прицепитесь к автору вопроса - почему вопрос задан не текстом, а картинкой. Почему-то это - реальное - нарушение вас не смущает.

Comment: @Harry вы верно путаете SO с задачником, где вам дают условия и проверяют ваши ответы в черном ящике по URL (который вы просите). SO - это про конкретные самодостаточные вопросы и ответы на них, а не "вот условие, вот решение, давайте угадаем почему ЧЯ по URL говорит что оно неверное!" :-)

Comment: @Kromster Забавно, как вы быстро соскакиваете с темы :) Поставьте тревогу на моем комментарии, пусть решает команда модераторов, насколько правомочно мое пожелание. Готовы? В любом случае - более обсуждать этот вопрос, тем более с вами, я не собираюсь.

Comment: @Harry с какой темы вам показалось произошел соскок? Про URL вроде бы все высказывались. Все при своих мнениях, живем дальше. А вот ваши прочие эскалации и провокации (цепляться к автору, ставить тревоги) мне не очень понятны. В любом случае, обсуждать их тут сейчас не вижу смысла тоже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подсказка: для решения необходимо найти максимум, это можно сделать при помощи математических операций `(a + b + abs(a - b)) / 2`. 
Но в данном случае используется модуль, что запрещено условиями задачи. Поэтому используем указанную в вопросе функцию модуля `sqrt(a * a)`.
Совмещаем решение и получаем новую формулу `(a + b + sqrt((a - b) * (a - b))) / 2`.
Теперь мы можем находить максимум, как же сравнить числа? Кажется, нужно просто разделить на первое число, но при делении на ноль решение упадёт. Поэтому будем из максимума вычитать первое число и прибавлять единицу.
**Итоговая формула:** `(a + b + sqrt((a - b) * (a - b))) / 2 - a + 1`

Answer (score 4):

Это в рамках разрешенного?

```
int m, n;
cin >> m >> n;
cout << !((unsigned int)(m - n) >> 31);
```

Ну, или, пожалуй

```
long long m, n;
cin >> m >> n;
cout << !((unsigned long long)(m - n) >> 63);
```

Answer (score 2):

как я вижу, это олимпиада "Сириус", сайт также принимает решения и на питоне, вот решение:

```
m = int(input()); n = int(input())

print( int(not '-' in str(m - n)) )
```

Comment: Действительно, в 6-7 классе можно выбрать язык программирования, но в 8 классе можно сдавать задачи только на C++

Comment: Понятно, попробуйте переформулировать моё решение

Answer (score 2):

Так разрешено?

```
s = m - n
try:
    a = 0**s
    print(1)
except:
    print(0)
```

Comment: Требуется решение на C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int max(int x, int y)
{
    return x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
}

int main()
{
    int m;
    cout << "m:\n";
    cin >> m;
    
    int n;
    cout << "n:\n";
    cin >> n;
    
    cout << "Out: " << (max(m, n) & 1) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Операторы сравнения использовать нельзя...

Answer (score 1):

Ещё несколько способов (предполагается, что переменные `m` и `n` имеют тип `long long`):

- `cout << !signbit(m-n);`
- `cout << !isnan(sqrt(m-n));`
- `cout << floor(1.0 + (m-n)/1e+10);`
- `cout << bool(to_string(m-n)[0] - '-');`
- `cout << (m-n + 5'000'000'000LL) / 5'000'000'000LL;`

Answer (score 1):

Более оптимальный вариант на ассемблере, без условных переходов.

```
#include <iostream>

int is_more_or_equal(int m, int n) {
  int8_t rv;
  asm(
    "sub %2,%0\n\t"
    "setge %1\n\t"
    : "+r" (n), "=q"(rv)
    : "r"(m)
  );
  return rv;
}

int main() {
  int m,n ;
  std::cin >> m >> n;
  std::cout << is_more_or_equal(m,n) << std::endl;
}
```

**Примечания**

- Ассемблерная вставка написана в расширенном синтаксисе gcc; cинтаксис ассемблера — at&t
- Используется инструкция [`setge`](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmd/SETcc), которая устанавливает единичный бит в соответствии с флагами, аналогично тому как `jge` совершает переход, т.е., говоря интуитивным языком, если «сравнение» на `>=` вернуло истину.
- Вместо `sub` можно использовать `cmp`. В таком случае ограничения на регистры можно будет ослабить.
- Для `setge` требуется восьмибитный регистр, поэтому для `rv` используется ограничение `q`, см. подробности [в документации gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints).

Answer (score 0):

На асме немножко:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

bool is_more_or_equal(int m, int n) {
    asm(
        ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
        "sub eax, %1;"
        "js L1;"
        "mov eax, 1;"
        "jmp L2;"
        "L1: "
        "mov eax, 0;"
        "L2: "
        ".att_syntax;"
        : // output
        : "r" (m), "r" (n) // input
    );
}

int main() {
    int m, n;
    std::cin >> m >> n;
    bool result = is_more_or_equal(m,n);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: условный переход ИМХО приравнивается к оператору сравнения, да и просто это субоптимельно для задачи... ну и с параметрами грязно работаешь...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, cmp можно приравнивать к оператору сравнения, а переход нет:)

Comment: практический смысл таких задач как раз в том, чтобы избавиться от условных переходов...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а у вас есть решение?

Comment: кстати, у тебя ещё некорректно будет работать, если переполнение при вычитании случиться...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, хочешь сказать что rax нужно использовать?

Comment: код — добавил ответом... что-то я малость подзабыл , как ассемблерные вставки пишутся... а по поводу переполнения — надо `jl` использовать вместо `js` — он проверяет и `OF` и `SF`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо. Да я тоже не каждый день пишу на ассемблере.